# Grub can't locate Windows 10 partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

Noob here: 
Split hard drive and now can't locate Windows10 partition or boot it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post this above to maintain format: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: disregard, so noobish couldnt link image of screenshot

Comment: [url=https://imgur.com/H0YAeNp][img]http://i.imgur.com/H0YAeNp.png[/img][/url]

Comment: For terminal output, just copy & paste into question and maintain format as code.